# reduceByKey results in Infinity value

Tags: scala, spark-streaming

I am trying to add values for same key.

```
val final= d1.join(d2).flatMap(line => Seq(line.swap._1)).reduceByKey((x, y) =>(x+y))
```

d1 and d2 are data streams. After flatMap I get Key value pair.

However, it is resulting in Infinity value in this line `reduceByKey((x, y) =>(x+y))`

for example, if the pairs are (k1,1.0) (k1,1.0) the line `reduceByKey((x, y) =>(x+y))` results in (k1,Infinity)

Any suggestion?

Comment: *if the pairs are (k1,1.0) (k1,1.0) the line reduceByKey((x, y) =>(x+y)) results in (k1,Infinity)* That's not  possible. The problem has to be somewhere outside of this code snippet

Comment: `flatMap(line => Seq(line.swap._1))` looses all keys and you will be adding (1.0, 1.0) + (1.0,1.0)  I don't think that's the intention. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Please include a [mcve], thanks

Comment: @maasg    `After d1.join(d2) The output is :
((0,number1),(2121947587,1.0))
((2,number3),(2121947587,1.0))
((1,number2),(2121947587,1.0))

After .flatMap(line => Seq(line.swap._1)) The output is:

(2121947587,1.0)
(2121947587,1.0)
(2121947587,1.0)

After .reduceByKey((x, y) =>(x+y)) I am expecting :

(2121947587,3.0)

Instead I get :

(2121947587,Infinity)

The strange thing is it works for second batch of input stream.`

Comment: @maasg I am still trying to figure out why it is not working for 1st batch of input. Shall I add anything more ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above code snippet is working. As @maasg righty hinted the problem was elsewhere. The error was caused by `division by zero` in previous code which I didnt post here. Thanks!